# ajax not working and chrome but working fine in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer, prototypejs

need help!!..it seems `new Ajax.Request` is not recognized based on the debug....
tried some of the recommendations online but not working..`cache=false` etc...
Thanks!

```
if (init) {
    init = false;
    param = "init=" + true;
    param = encodeURI(param.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));


    setLastRequestTimestamp(); //ryan's trial
    new Ajax.Request("downstocking_apply_async.do", {
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            if (!isHangingRequest()) {
                alert("initUpdateScanArea");
                initUpdateScanArea(transport.responseText);
                setLastRequestTimestamp();
            } else {
                if (signalOnScan() == 1) {
                    alert("<fmt:message key="
                        message.signal_scan_off " bundle="
                        $ {
                            application
                        }
                        "/>");
                    return;
                }
                alert("<fmt:message key="
                    message.signal_downstock_suspend " bundle="
                    $ {
                        application
                    }
                    "/>");
                doSuspend();

            }
        },
        onFailure: function(transport) {
            if (!isHangingRequest()) {
                document.downstockingForm.action = "downstocking_apply_async.do?" + param;
                if (signalOnScan() == 1) {
                    alert("<fmt:message key="
                        message.signal_scan_off "    bundle="
                        $ {
                            application
                        }
                        "/>");
                    return;
                }
                setLastRequestTimestamp();
                document.downstockingForm.submit();
            } else {
                if (signalOnScan() == 1) {
                    alert("message");
                    return;
                }
                alert("message");
                doSuspend();

            }
        },
        parameters: param,
        asynchronous: "true"
    });
}
```

Comment: What error are you seeing exactly?

Comment: If `new Ajax.Request` is not being recognized, there's probably something wrong with how you're loading prototype.js.

Comment: added this in the page to load prototype.js (latest 1.7.3) <script language="JavaScript" src="prototype.js"></script>

Comment: Jordan S..not receiving any error but it is not displaying the responseText...

Answer (score 0):

found the solution...a custom js library that was imported is creating confusion with prototype js
Removed the custom library and it works now... thanks!